# How to detect and use unusual mouse buttons?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have a [G300 gaming mouse](http://support.logitech.com/en_gb/product/gaming-mouse-g300) on Windows 10 and would like to bind actions to the buttons, including the more exotic ones (there are nine buttons and the wheel).

**How can I discover what the code of a button is, from AHK perspective?**

Answer (score 2):

- Make a new script (or use one you have) that's persistent (`#Persistent`) or has hotkey definitions that keep it from exiting immediately
- For easiest results you will also want `#InstallKeybdHook` and `#InstallMouseHook`
- Run the AutoHotkey script
- An 'H' icon should show up in the System Tray
- Right click on the icon and select `Open` to open the program that's running
- Menu > View > Key History and Script Info
- Click the mouse buttons that you want to get VK / SC codes for
- Click the Key History window again and Refresh with F5
- The button codes should now be listed and may be used as VK / SC codes per AutoHotkey documentation

Comment: Also, I don't have that particular Logitech mouse, but something else I do sometimes is just use the mouse-specific software to bind buttons to normal key combinations that aren't used.  For example, you could map a special button to Alt+Shift+Control+F9 (random key combo) and then use AutoHotkey to detect that key combination once it's sent by the mouse driver/software.  That will only work in limited cases though--better to use direct mapping if you can do so.

Comment: That's probably the best option, outside actually using the built in software. With my razer gear, some additional/macro keys don't activate without a magic packet being sent - so if the buttons do nothing, logitech may be doing the same

Comment: For the AutoHotKey v2, the commands are just `InstallMouseHook` and `InstallKeybdHook` without the leading `#` - see [AHK Docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/InstallMouseHook.htm)

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the [documentation](http://www.logitech.com/assets/42321/2/g300-quick-start-guide.pdf)

> You can customize the G300’s three onboard profiles, including
>   buttons, tracking behavior, and illumination color, using the
>   Logitech® Gaming Software. Download his free software at
>   www.logitech.com/downloads. To learn how to customize the G300,
>   download a PDF user’s guide at www.logitech.com/G300.

Comment: Reading documentation? Novel! Unfortunately the OP does specify using AHK...

Comment: my bad, didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the xev terminal program. This will allow you to click with your odd buttons and produce codes that represent them.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I forgot to mention that I am on Windows

Comment: My apologies, I was assuming linux. I am not sure on the Windows side :)